# Having difficulty in understanding wordpress Plugin data

Tags: wordpress

I am beginner at wordpress world. I am having difficulty to retrieve the intended value from following data.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => MCQ Botany 101
            [settings] => a:24:{s:9:"limit_one";s:2:"no";s:12:"limit_one_wp";s:2:"no";s:16:"limit_one_cookie";s:2:"no";s:11:"save_resume";s:2:"no";s:16:"question_numbers";s:3:"yes";s:5:"timer";s:4:"5000";s:9:"pass_mark";s:2:"80";s:17:"show_progress_bar";s:3:"yes";s:20:"automark_whenfreetxt";s:2:"no";s:14:"finish_display";s:11:"Quiz Review";s:6:"status";s:7:"enabled";s:9:"send_user";s:2:"no";s:7:"contact";s:2:"no";s:6:"use_wp";s:2:"no";s:16:"notificaton_type";s:7:"instant";s:14:"email_template";s:0:"";s:12:"pdf_template";s:0:"";s:7:"use_pdf";s:2:"no";s:13:"store_results";s:3:"yes";s:18:"notification_email";s:0:"";s:14:"finish_message";s:0:"";s:11:"pass_finish";s:2:"no";s:19:"pass_finish_message";s:0:"";s:11:"fail_review";s:3:"yes";}
            [type] => quiz
            [timestamp] => 2016-07-10 21:02:44
        )
)
```

I want 5000 from `s:4:"5000"`. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array, which has an object as a first key. You want to get a 'settings' value from this object, but it's a serialized string. So you need to [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it first.

Assuming that `$myArr` is the given array you'll do something like this:

```
$settingsArr = unserialize($myArr[0]->settings);

$settingsArr['timer'];
```

Because the `timer` key holds the `5000` value.

You can recreate this in [php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/):

```
<?php

$myObj = new stdClass;
$myObj->id = 1;
$myObj->name = 'MCQ Botany 101';
$myObj->settings = 'a:24:{s:9:"limit_one";s:2:"no";s:12:"limit_one_wp";s:2:"no";s:16:"limit_one_cookie";s:2:"no";s:11:"save_resume";s:2:"no";s:16:"question_numbers";s:3:"yes";s:5:"timer";s:4:"5000";s:9:"pass_mark";s:2:"80";s:17:"show_progress_bar";s:3:"yes";s:20:"automark_whenfreetxt";s:2:"no";s:14:"finish_display";s:11:"Quiz Review";s:6:"status";s:7:"enabled";s:9:"send_user";s:2:"no";s:7:"contact";s:2:"no";s:6:"use_wp";s:2:"no";s:16:"notificaton_type";s:7:"instant";s:14:"email_template";s:0:"";s:12:"pdf_template";s:0:"";s:7:"use_pdf";s:2:"no";s:13:"store_results";s:3:"yes";s:18:"notification_email";s:0:"";s:14:"finish_message";s:0:"";s:11:"pass_finish";s:2:"no";s:19:"pass_finish_message";s:0:"";s:11:"fail_review";s:3:"yes";}';
$myObj->type = 'quiz';
$myObj->timestamp = '2016-07-10 21:02:44';

$myArr = array(
    '0' => $myObj
);

$settingsArr = unserialize($myArr[0]->settings);

print_r($settingsArr['timer']);
```

You can also see the contents of the settings array

```
print_r($settingsArr);

Array
(
    [limit_one] => no
    [limit_one_wp] => no
    [limit_one_cookie] => no
    [save_resume] => no
    [question_numbers] => yes
    [timer] => 5000
    [pass_mark] => 80
    [show_progress_bar] => yes
    [automark_whenfreetxt] => no
    [finish_display] => Quiz Review
    [status] => enabled
    [send_user] => no
    [contact] => no
    [use_wp] => no
    [notificaton_type] => instant
    [email_template] => 
    [pdf_template] => 
    [use_pdf] => no
    [store_results] => yes
    [notification_email] => 
    [finish_message] => 
    [pass_finish] => no
    [pass_finish_message] => 
    [fail_review] => yes
)
```

Comment: Thanks a million dingo_d.

Comment: If the answer helped feel free to up vote it and accept :)

Comment: @kuldeepsharma please remember to accept the answer that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean. It is hard to find out how these **serialized** string called, if you never worked with them.

Please look into:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize

For More info visit the PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

I think that should help you to work unserialize and serialize them again.